# SQL query with contains / isabout works perfect in SQL Server Management Studio, but it does not in code behind

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I would like to ask what I am doing wrong. I have this query that works perfectly in SQL Server Management Studio:

```
select * 
from products, containstable(products, prod, 'isabout("laptop anybrand" weight (1))') as resultado 
where products.ImageIDS = resultado.[Key] 
order by resultado.[Rank] desc
```

But when I put it into the code-behind, it does not work, and is like this:

```
select * 
from products, containstable(products, prod,'isabout(" + searcht.Text + " weight (1))') as resultado 
where products.ImageIDS = resultado.[Key] 
order by resultado.[Rank] desc
```

The debugger does not send any error, but it does not work, next I am posting the code that I am using the whole query:

```
Private Sub BindGrid2()
    Dim use As SqlConnection

    use = New SqlConnection("Data Source=DESKTOP-50SIV8B\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=cupon2; User ID=XXXX; password=XXXX")
    use.Open()

    Dim queryy As String = "select * from products, containstable(products, prod,'isabout(" + searcht.Text + " weight (1))') as resultado where products.ImageIDS = resultado.[Key] order by resultado.[Rank] desc"

    Dim DAA As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(queryy, use)
    Dim DTT As New Data.DataTable

    searchid.Text = ""
    subc.Items.Clear()
    ids.Items.Clear()

    DAA.Fill(DTT)

    gv2.DataSource = DTT
    gv2.DataBind()

    use.Close()
End Sub
```

Hope anyone can help me what is wrong.

Thanks!

Comment: Yikes, this looks scary-vulnerable to sql injection issues. Also, it will leave the connection hanging open if an exception is thrown (look into `Using` blocks), and _no one_ should be writing `A, B` style joins anymore. They've been obsolete for 25 years.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn 30 years, even!

Answer (score 1):

Look at this string literal from the SSMS query:

```
'isabout("laptop anybrand" weight (1))'
```

Note the literal itself contains double-quotes around the search key.

Now look at the VB excerpt:

```
'isabout(" + searcht.Text + " weight (1))'
```

There are double quotes here, but they are **not** part of the final query, and there's nothing in the code to make sure they are added.

What you should do is change the SSMS version like this:

```sql
DECLARE @SearchKey nvarchar(50) = N'laptop anybrand'
SELECT ... containstable(products, prod, N'isabout("' + @SearchKey  + '" weight (1))')
```

You may have to play with this some in SSMS to get it working again, but when it is do the same thing in VB. Note the comments I added:

```vb
'Move all your database code into it's own module!
Friend Module DB
    Private connectString As String = "Data Source=DESKTOP-50SIV8B\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=cupon2; User ID=XXXX; password=XXXX"

    Public Function SearchProducts(searchKey As String) As DataTable
        'String literals can be more than one line now
        Dim query As String = "
SELECT * 
FROM products p
INNER JOIN containstable(products, prod,'isabout("" + @SearchKey + "" weight (1))') as resultado 
    ON p.ImageIDS = resultado.[Key] 
ORDER BY resultado.[Rank] DESC"

        Dim result As New DataTable()
        'Using blocks guarantee the connection is closed, **even if an exception is thrown!**
        Using cn As New SqlConnection(connectString), _
              cmd As New SqlCommand(query, cn), _
              da As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)

             'Parameterized queries stop lots of bugs, hackers, and are **faster**
             cmd.Parameters.Add("@SearchKey", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = searchKey
             da.Fill(result)
        End Using
        Return result.Tables(0)
    End Function
End Module

Private Sub BindGrid2()
    searchid.Text = ""
    subc.Items.Clear()
    ids.Items.Clear()

    gv2.DataSource = DB.SearchProducts(searcht.Text)
    gv2.DataBind()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer, it is complete but, I found an easier solution. Which is:

```
String.Format("select * from products, freetexttable(products, prod,'isabout({0}{1}{2} weight (1))') as resultado where products.ImageIDS = resultado.[Key] order by resultado.[Rank] desc", """", searcht.Text.Trim(), """")
```